# Pyramid on App Engine gets "InvalidResponseError: header values must be str, got 'unicode'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyramid

I am using Pyramid 1.3 with the AppEngine 1.6.4 SDK on OS X 10.7.3. I am using Python 2.7 and have threadsafe true in app.yaml.

```
@view_config(route_name='manager_swms', permission='manager', renderer='manager/swms.jinja2')
def manager_swms(request):
    """Generates blobstore url and passes users swms in swms table"""

    # generate url for any form upload that may occur
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_swm')

    user = get_current_user(request)
    swms = DBSession.query(SWMS).filter_by(owner_id=int(user.id)).all()

    return {
        "analytics_id": analytics_id,
        "user": get_current_user(request),
        "upload_url": upload_url,
        "swms": [(x.filename, x.blob_key) for x in swms]
    }

class BlobstoreUploadHandler(object):
    """Base class for creation blob upload handlers."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__uploads = None

    def get_uploads(self, field_name=None):
        """Get uploads sent to this handler.

        Args:
          field_name: Only select uploads that were sent as a specific field.

        Returns:
          A list of BlobInfo records corresponding to each upload.
          Empty list if there are no blob-info records for field_name.
        """
        if self.__uploads is None:
            self.__uploads = {}
            for key, value in self.request.params.items():
                if isinstance(value, cgi.FieldStorage):
                    if 'blob-key' in value.type_options:
                        self.__uploads.setdefault(key, []).append(
                            blobstore.parse_blob_info(value))

        if field_name:
            try:
                return list(self.__uploads[field_name])
            except KeyError:
                return []
        else:
            results = []
            for uploads in self.__uploads.itervalues():
                results += uploads
            return results

@view_config(route_name='upload_swm', permission='manager')
class UploadHandler(BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    ''' Handles redirects from Blobstore uploads. '''

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        super(UploadHandler, self).__init__()

    def __call__(self):

        user = get_current_user(self.request)
        for blob_info in self.get_uploads('file'):

            new_swm = SWMS(
                owner_id = int(user.id),
                blob_key = str(blob_info.key()),
                filename = blob_info.filename,
                size = blob_info.size,
            )
            DBSession.add(new_swm)
        DBSession.flush()

        # redirect to swms page
        return HTTPFound(location='/manager/swms')
```

In the above code, manager_swms() generates a page which includes a form for uploading a file into the Blobstore. The form works OK and I can see the blob appear in the Blobstore when the form is used. The redirect from the blobstore POST is then to /upload_swm where I successfully take BlobInfo details and place them into a SQL table. All of this is good and the final thing I want to do is redirect to the first page so another file can be uploaded if need be and I can show the list of files uploaded.

As per Pyramid documentation, I am using HTTPFound(location='/manager/swms') [the original page URL] to try and redirect however I get:

```
ERROR    2012-03-29 22:56:38,170 wsgi.py:208] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tim/work/OHSPro/var/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    result = handler(self._environ, self._StartResponse)
  File "lib/dist/pyramid/router.py", line 195, in __call__
    foo = response(request.environ, start_response)
  File "lib/dist/pyramid/httpexceptions.py", line 291, in __call__
    foo = Response.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
  File "lib/dist/webob/response.py", line 922, in __call__
    start_response(self.status, headerlist)
  File "/Users/tim/work/OHSPro/var/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 150, in _StartResponse
    _GetTypeName(header[1]))
InvalidResponseError: header values must be str, got 'unicode'
INFO     2012-03-29 22:56:38,174 dev_appserver_blobstore.py:408] Upload handler returned 500
INFO     2012-03-29 22:56:38,193 dev_appserver.py:2884] "POST /_ah/upload/ahJkZXZ-cHJvdG8tc2NvaHNwcm9yGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgTDA HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

AppEngine is clearly objecting to unicode in the HTTP header but I'm not doing anything unusual AFAIK. If I drop into pdb and take a look at the HTTPFound object, the headers are:

```
ResponseHeaders([('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'), ('Content-Length', '0'), ('Location', '/manager/swms')])
```

Why would I get a unicode problem from these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so it looks like you are overriding appengine's supported webob which is 1.1.1 on the [2.7 runtime.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27) And pyramid 1.3 depends on webob>=1.2. This is most likely the problem because it was the Blobstore handler stuff that was keeping the sdk held back at webob==0.9 until SDK 1.6.4 was released.

FWIW, this problem is expected to be resolved by SDK 1.6.5 (late April). The only reason I know this is because I was trying to get all this crap resolved when the 2.7 runtime was deemed ready for general use, yet the SDK didn't support it. see this [issue](https://github.com/Pylons/webob/issues/14) for more details.

If possible, I would suggest running it with pyramid 1.2, I know that works fine on appengine. And Just hold off on moving to 1.3 for a few weeks. :)

Comment: Yes, we are using WebOb 1.2 because of Pyramid's dependencies. I tracked down the issue to the WSGI environ providing wsgi.url_scheme as u'http' - which seems weird to me. WebOb's response.py uses that to create headers (see line 1138 at https://github.com/Pylons/webob/blob/master/webob/response.py) so I have simply wrapped the 'return url' as 'return str(url)'. With this, blobs are loading fine into the datastore (local and production), although I haven't tried retrieving yet.                    PS Above, I think you mean >=1.2 not <=1.2

Comment: FWIW, I have got both uploads and downloads to/from the Blobstore working fine with Pyramid 1.3 on GAE. I took the webapp-based Handler objects from the SDK and modified them to work with Pyramid view callable classes. For the DownloadHandler, not needing to extract byte ranges, I took out the range related code. It all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer... adding a str() fixes the problem, but not the root cause. I spent hours trying to figure out why one particular redirect raised this error while others didn't, before noticing that the URL for the bad redirect was missing the initial "/".

I have no idea *why* this is the case - possibly an incomplete path is processed differently from a complete one. But if you hit this error try changing:

```
self.redirect('home.view')
```

to:

```
self.redirect('/home.view')
```